# Is there a PG issue with multiple AJAX submissions in a Rails Rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec

I'm running integration tests on my Rails app using a PG database, Rspec, Capybara and the poltergeist gem for javascript submissions. Essentially I'm testing the flow/presentation of questions in a question tree - and in my rspec tests I click and answer, submit via AJAX, then test that the correct next_question is appearing. This works fine when testing 1/2 questions deep, but once I start submitting >3 questions in series using JS, I get the following error:

```
 PG::Error:
   result has been cleared
```

I'm also seeing:

```
Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, password: 'Foobar') }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

Errors like this crop up, which don't if I remove the offending deep js submissions.

Here's the code that fails:

```
    describe 'the Sales Opportunity access to Sale Qualifiers view', :type => :feature do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, password: 'Foobar') }
    let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company, organization: user.organization)}
    let(:sales_opportunity) { FactoryGirl.create(:sales_opportunity, company: company, user: user) }
    let(:sale_qualifier) { FactoryGirl.create(:sale_qualifier, sales_opportunity: sales_opportunity) }
    let(:answer) { sale_qualifier.create_answer(answer_text: 'I am the answer to question 1')}

      before(:each) do
       sign_in user
       visit sales_opportunity_path(sales_opportunity)
   end

    it 'tests submitting more than one question answer', js: true do
     within('#qualifier_tabs') do
      page.click_link('Fit')
      sleep 1
      end
      within('#qualifier_panel') do
        expect(page).to have_content('Has the company released formal requirements to demonstrate against, or an RFI or RFP?')
        page.select('Yes', from: 'sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text')
        page.click_button('Submit')
        sleep 1
        expect(page).to have_content('Briefly describe the most important requirements')
        expect(page).to have_selector('textarea#sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text')
        page.fill_in('sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text', with: "some important requirements")
        page.click_button('Submit')
        sleep 1
        expect(page).to have_content('How well do your products or services match these requirements?')
        expect(page).to have_selector('select#sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text')
        page.select('Good fit', from: 'sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text')
        page.click_button('Submit')
      end
  end
```

Is this caused by the number of AJAX submissions in series? If so, how would I test this (at first glance it seems I can test the submit button, but I'd need to build a series of answers in FactoryGirl and then test the view rather than using `js: true` AJAX submissions.

Comment: Are you using database_cleaner to clean your database before spec ? https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: No, I'm not using that. I was under the impression it's not required these days and I didn't want to bloat my gemfile.